# Ionic how to filter array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ionic3

can someone please help me with some code to filter an array in ionic, so i have i have to buttons, incomplete and complete. and within the array there's status if the status value is greater than 0 then the item should move to complete. Here is the array:

```
var prod = [{
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "152737",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "id": "282",
        "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
        "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
        "price": "40.69"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "155565",
        "order_qty": "3",
        "status": "3",
        "id": "283",
        "sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3",
        "prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6",
        "price": "65.99"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "148155",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "285",
        "sku": "2477f9462d50d0e7b40631c1a347b2",
        "prod_name": "Pnp Chicken 4 Thighs And 4 Drumsticks",
        "price": "34.86"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "137924",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "290",
        "sku": "a6d978c328234fe6fcaa2b1bb40cfc",
        "prod_name": "Purina Husky Chunks In Jelly Chicken 775g x6",
        "price": "128.63"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "158980",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "291",
        "sku": "ddcbbd19c55637095f8d27895d689c",
        "prod_name": "Willow Creek Estate Blend Squeeze Me Olive Oil 1 Litre",
        "price": "189.19"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "158650",
        "order_qty": "8",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "292",
        "sku": "2128f0c6913ea2ef3730bc11c6a90d",
        "prod_name": "Bakers Good Morning Milk&cereal 50gr",
        "price": "7.69"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter

```js
var prod = [{
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "152737",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "id": "282",
        "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
        "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
        "price": "40.69"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "155565",
        "order_qty": "3",
        "status": "3",
        "id": "283",
        "sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3",
        "prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6",
        "price": "65.99"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "148155",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "285",
        "sku": "2477f9462d50d0e7b40631c1a347b2",
        "prod_name": "Pnp Chicken 4 Thighs And 4 Drumsticks",
        "price": "34.86"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "137924",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "290",
        "sku": "a6d978c328234fe6fcaa2b1bb40cfc",
        "prod_name": "Purina Husky Chunks In Jelly Chicken 775g x6",
        "price": "128.63"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "158980",
        "order_qty": "1",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "291",
        "sku": "ddcbbd19c55637095f8d27895d689c",
        "prod_name": "Willow Creek Estate Blend Squeeze Me Olive Oil 1 Litre",
        "price": "189.19"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "241918",
        "product_id": "158650",
        "order_qty": "8",
        "status": "0",
        "id": "292",
        "sku": "2128f0c6913ea2ef3730bc11c6a90d",
        "prod_name": "Bakers Good Morning Milk&cereal 50gr",
        "price": "7.69"
    }
];

var completeProd = prod.filter(x => x.status && parseInt(x.status) > 0);
console.log("completeProd : ");
console.log(completeProd);

var inCompleteProd = prod.filter(x => x.status && parseInt(x.status) == 0);
console.log("inCompleteProd : ");
console.log(inCompleteProd);
```